# Make a path selectable in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to be able to draw a line in swiftui where only the line is selectable, this works fine for vertical and horizontal lines but when the line is on an angle the hit area

My code for drawing a line from one corner of the frame to the other:

```
struct AngleLine: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my view I put this into a button

```
struct LineSelector: View {
    var lineWidth : CGFloat
    let dash : [CGFloat] = [6, 3]
    let size : CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack{
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Hello")
            }) {
                AngleLine().stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: lineWidth, dash: [6, 3])).fill(Color.red)
                
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

See this image for the result.
[image: Line on screen]

The issue is that now the frame fills the entire screen and everything becomes the button, when the goal is to only have the line be a button, not the entire frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of wrapping your `AngleLine()` with a `Button` you can add a `.onTapGesture{}` into the `Shape` object. See the following code

```
AngleLine().stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: lineWidth, dash: [6, 3])).fill(Color.red)
    .onTapGesture { // <-- Adding the tap gesture
        print("Hello")
    }
```

This will prevent the entire frame of the shape from acting as a button. See the output of the above code, below.

[image]